# How to find value for/match to coordinates of closest proximity in a second df

Tags: r, coordinates, match

I have a series of geographical positions at sea which I am trying to get geological sediment type information for. I am using an export of the national british geological sediment database (df1)which is a large data set of coordinates and sediment information. 
Currently I have been rounding the coordinates in the BGS export file (df1) and averaging/recalculating the sediment type for these coordinate squares, then I have rounded my coordinates in (df2) and matched these to these squares to get a sediment classification.

The BGS export looks like this (df1);

```
    NUM     X       Y           GRAV    SAND    MUD
1   228     1.93656 52.31307    1.07    98.83   0.10
2   142     1.84667 52.45333    0.00    52.60   47.40
3   182     1.91950 52.17750    9.48    90.38   0.14
4   124     1.88333 52.70833    0.00    98.80   1.20
5   2807    1.91050 51.45000    2.05    97.91   0.05
6   2787    1.74683 51.99382    41.32   52.08   6.60
7   2776    1.66117 51.63550    9.83    87.36   2.81
8   2763    1.82467 51.71767    43.92   47.25   8.83
9   2753    1.76867 51.96349    57.66   39.18   3.15
10  68      2.86967 52.96333    0.30    98.90   0.80
11  2912    1.70083 51.77783    26.90   64.87   8.22
12  2914    1.59750 51.88882    32.00   65.02   2.97
13  2886    1.98833 51.34267    1.05    98.91   0.04
14  2891    1.87817 51.31549    68.57   31.34   0.08
15  2898    1.37433 51.41249    35.93   61.48   2.59
16  45      2.06667 51.82500    9.70    88.10   2.20
17  2904    1.63617 51.45999    16.28   66.67   17.05
```

My positions at sea look like this (df2);

```
haul    DecStartLat DecStartLong
1993H_2 55.23983    -5.512830
2794H_1 55.26670    -5.516700
1993H_1 55.27183    -5.521330
0709A_71    55.26569    -5.519730
0396H_2 55.44120    -5.917800
0299H_2 55.44015    -5.917310
0514A_26    55.46897    -5.912167
0411A_64    55.47289    -5.911820
0410A_65    55.46869    -5.911930
0514A_24    55.63585    -5.783500
0295H_4 55.57250    -5.754300
0410A_62    55.63656    -6.041870
0413A_53    55.73280    -6.020600
0396H_13    55.66470    -6.002300
2794H_8 55.83330    -5.883300
0612A_15    55.84025    -5.912130
0410A_74    55.84311    -5.910180
0299H_16    55.90568    -5.732490
0200H_18    55.88600    -5.742900
0612A_18    55.90450    -5.835880
```

This is my script...

```
get.Sed.type <- function(x,y) {
  x$Y2 <- round(x$Y, digits=1)
  x$X2 <- round(x$X, digits=1)
  x$BGSQ <- paste(x$Y2,x$X2,sep="_")
  x$RATIO <- x$SAND/x$MUD
  x <- aggregate(cbind(GRAV,RATIO)~BGSQ,data=x,FUN=mean)

  FOLK <- (x$GRAV)
  FOLK[(FOLK)<1] <- 0
  FOLK[(FOLK)>=1&(FOLK)<5] <- 1
  FOLK[(FOLK)>=5&(FOLK)<30] <- 5
  FOLK[(FOLK)>=30&(FOLK)<80] <- 30
  FOLK[(FOLK)>=80] <- 80

  R_CLASS <- (x$RATIO)
  R_CLASS[(R_CLASS)<1/9] <- 0
  R_CLASS[(R_CLASS)>=1/9&(R_CLASS)<1] <- 0.1
  R_CLASS[(R_CLASS)>=1&(R_CLASS)<9] <- 1
  R_CLASS[(R_CLASS)>=9] <- 9

  x$FOLK_CLASS <- NULL
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==0&(FOLK)==0] <- "M"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)%in%c(0,0.1)&(FOLK)==5] <- "gM"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==0.1&(FOLK)==0] <- "sM"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==0&(FOLK)==1] <- "(g)M"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==0.1&(FOLK)==1] <- "(g)sM"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==9&(FOLK)==0] <- "S"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==1&(FOLK)==0] <- "mS"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==9&(FOLK)==1] <- "(g)S"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==1&(FOLK)==1] <- "(g)sM"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==1&(FOLK)==5] <- "gmS"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==9&(FOLK)==5] <- "gS"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(FOLK)==80] <- "G"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)%in%c(0,0.1)&(FOLK)==30] <- "mG"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==1&(FOLK)==30] <- "msG"
  x$FOLK_CLASS[(R_CLASS)==9&(FOLK)==30] <- "sG"

  y$Lat <- round(y$DecStartLat, digits=1)
  y$Long <- round(y$DecStartLong, digits=1)
  y$LATLONG100_sq <- paste(y$Lat,y$Long,sep="_")

  y <- merge(y, x[,c(1,4)],all.x=TRUE,by.x="LATLONG100_sq",by.y="BGSQ")

  #Delete unwanted columns
  y <- y[, !(colnames(y) %in% c("Lat","Long","LATLONG100_sq"))]
  #Name column something logical
  colnames(y)[colnames(y) == 'FOLK_CLASS'] <- 'BGS_class'

  return(y)
}
```

However I have a dozen or so positions in db2 for which there are no corresponding values in the BGS export (db1), I want to know how I can either ask it to do another average for the squares surrounding that respective square (i.e. round to a larger number and repeat the process) OR to ask it to find the coordinate in the BGS export file that is closest in proximity and take the existing value.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to limit the samples you post to the bare minimum needed to answer the question. The data and script you've posted contain a lot of irrelevant stuff, which makes it harder to answer. also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382708/mapping-x-y-coordinates-to-nearest-point-of-a-set-in-r/47383101#47383101 could help

Answer (score 1):

Going for the second option stated in the question, I suggest to frame the question as follows:

Say that you have a set of m coordinates from db1 and n coordinates from db2, m <=n, and that currently the intersection of these sets is empty.

You'd like to match each point from db1 with a point from db2 such that the "error" of the matching, e.g. sum of distances, will be minimized.

A simple greedy approach for solving this might be to generate an m x n matrix with the distances between each pair of coordinates, and sequentially select the closest match for each point.
Of course, If there are many points to match, or if you're after an optimal solution, you may want to consider more elaborate matching algorithms (e.g. the [Hungarian algorithm](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hungarian_algorithm)).

Code:

```
  #generate some data (this data will generate sub-optimal matching with greedy matching)
  db1 <- data.frame(id=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"), x=c(1,5,10,20), y=c(1,5,10,20))
  db2 <- data.frame(id=c("b1","b2","b3","b4"),x=c(1.1,2.1,8.1,14.1), y=c(1.1,1.1,8.1,14.1))

  #create cartesian product
  product <- merge(db1, db2, by=NULL)
  #calculate auclidean distances for each possible matching
  product$d <- sqrt((product$x.x - product$x.y)^2 + (product$y.x - product$y.y)^2)

  #(naively & greedily) find the best match for each point
  sorted <- product[ order(product[,"d"]), ]
  found <- vector()
  res <- vector() #this vector will hold the result
  for (i in 1:nrow(db1)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(sorted)) {
      db2_val <- as.character(sorted[j,"id.y"])
      if (sorted[j,"id.x"] == db1[i, "id"] && length(grep(db2_val, found)) == 0) {    
        #print(paste("matching ", db1[i, "id"], " with ", db2_val))
        res[i] <- db2_val      
        found <- c(found, db2_val)
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that I'm sure the code can be improved and made more elegant by using methods other than loop.

Comment: Could you save time by iterating over `for (j in i:nrow(sorted))` in the inner loop?

Comment: @BondedDust, no, I don't think that you can, e.g. consider the case where the first element of the sorted dataframe relates to the second db1 element. Then when i equals 2, the best match would be this first element.

Comment: So "best-matchness" is not transitive?

Comment: This is a greedy solution, not an optimal one, so it well may be non-transitive...

Comment: So if `y` is a best match to `x` there still might be a better match to `y`?

Comment: Since the algorithm is not optimal, the "best match" found by it is not necessarily the globally best match. So e.g. a different ordering of the elements, or different order of iteration, might still generate a "better" match, in the sense that the global sum of distances will be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I do not misunderstand, but as far as I get from the title, you need to match based on minimum distance. If this distance is allowed to be [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), then one can use the fast [RANN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RANN/index.html), if not, then one needs to compute the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

#### Some of the provided data

```
BGS_df <- 
  read.table(text = 
               "    NUM     X       Y           GRAV    SAND    MUD
                1   228     1.93656 52.31307    1.07    98.83   0.10
                2   142     1.84667 52.45333    0.00    52.60   47.40
                3   182     1.91950 52.17750    9.48    90.38   0.14
                4   124     1.88333 52.70833    0.00    98.80   1.20
                5   2807    1.91050 51.45000    2.05    97.91   0.05",
             header = TRUE)

my_positions <-
  read.table(text = 
               "haul    DecStartLat DecStartLong
                1993H_2 55.23983    -5.512830
                2794H_1 55.26670    -5.516700
                1993H_1 55.27183    -5.521330",
             header = TRUE)
```

#### Euclidean distance (using `RANN` package)

```
library(RANN)
# For each point in my_positions, find the nearest neighbor from BGS_df:
# Give X and then Y (longtitude and then latitude)
# Note that argument k sets the number of nearest neighbours, here 1 (the closest)
closest_RANN <- RANN::nn2(data = BGS_df[, c("X", "Y")], 
                          query = my_positions[, c("DecStartLong", "DecStartLat")], 
                          k = 1)
results_RANN <- cbind(my_positions[, c("haul", "DecStartLong", "DecStartLat")],
                      BGS_df[closest_RANN$nn.idx, ])
results_RANN
#        haul DecStartLong DecStartLat NUM       X        Y GRAV SAND MUD
# 4   1993H_2     -5.51283    55.23983 124 1.88333 52.70833    0 98.8 1.2
# 4.1 2794H_1     -5.51670    55.26670 124 1.88333 52.70833    0 98.8 1.2
# 4.2 1993H_1     -5.52133    55.27183 124 1.88333 52.70833    0 98.8 1.2
```

#### Great circle distance (using `geosphere` package)

```
library(geosphere)
# Compute matrix of great circle distances
dist_mat <- geosphere::distm(x = BGS_df[, c("X", "Y")],
                             y = my_positions[, c("DecStartLong", "DecStartLat")],
                             fun = distHaversine) # can try other distances
# For each column (point in my_positions) get the index of row of min dist
# (corresponds to row index in BGS_df) 
BGS_idx <- apply(dist_mat, 2, which.min)

results_geo <- cbind(my_positions[, c("haul", "DecStartLong", "DecStartLat")],
                     BGS_df[BGS_idx, ])
identical(results_geo, results_RANN) # here TRUE, but not always expected
```