# Mapping (x, y) coordinates to nearest point of a set in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am building a shiny application, and I have a line of code that is currently slowing me down quite a bit. I have the following dataframe, with 1008 unique (x,y) coordinates (apologies for the large copy and paste, although I think sharing this whole dataframe is helpful):

```
dput(rounded_coords)
structure(list(xspots = c(1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 
14.5, 16, 17.5, 19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 
34, 35.5, 37, 38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 
4.75, 6.25, 7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 
19.75, 21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 
33.25, 34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 
46.75, 48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 
17.5, 19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 
37, 38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 
6.25, 7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49, 1.75, 3.25, 4.75, 6.25, 
7.75, 9.25, 10.75, 12.25, 13.75, 15.25, 16.75, 18.25, 19.75, 
21.25, 22.75, 24.25, 25.75, 27.25, 28.75, 30.25, 31.75, 33.25, 
34.75, 36.25, 37.75, 39.25, 40.75, 42.25, 43.75, 45.25, 46.75, 
48.25, 1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10, 11.5, 13, 14.5, 16, 17.5, 
19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28, 29.5, 31, 32.5, 34, 35.5, 37, 
38.5, 40, 41.5, 43, 44.5, 46, 47.5, 49), yspots = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 
17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 
17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 
17.5, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 
23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 
23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 
23.5, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 
26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 
26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 
26.5, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 
29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 
29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 
29.5, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 
32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 
32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 32.5, 
32.5, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 
35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 
35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 35.5, 
35.5, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 
38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 
38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 
38.5, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 
41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 
41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 
41.5, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 
44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 
44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 
44.5, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46)), .Names = c("xspots", "yspots"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1008L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a second dataframe as well, *unrounded_coords*, and I would like to round the values in *unrounded_coords* to its nearest value in *rounded_coords*. A subset of my dataframe *unrounded_coords* is shared below:

```
dput(unrounded_coords[1:100, ])
structure(list(xmapped = c(24.9, 23.2, 3.6, 11.9, 26, 29.7, 46.7, 
13.3, 23.9, 24.5, 24.1, 34.6, 24.3, 39.8, 35.9, 25.2, 19.7, 36.7, 
3.2, 24.5, 34.2, 36.2, 24.4, 10.5, 31.5, 25.8, 31.4, 18, 25.3, 
25, 25.9, 24.5, 24.8, 8.6, 5.8, 23.4, 48.2, 38.5, 24, 9, 30.4, 
8.2, 32, 22.3, 24.9, 41.9, 28.1, 26.3, 34.8, 19.8, 2.2, 25.8, 
14.3, 25.3, 6.3, 25.3, 23.8, 5.1, 6.7, 24.8, 24.2, 25.6, 47.2, 
25.3, 25, 39.1, 48.9, 23.9, 40, 24.1, 12.4, 12.5, 5.4, 32, 14.3, 
26.4, 41.2, 32.7, 25.2, 23.7, 38.1, 25.6, 31.9, 43.3, 22.2, 27.9, 
34.6, 41.6, 36.8, 26.3, 25.9, 25, 24.4, 24.4, 27, 29.1, 24.8, 
4, 18, 27.4), ymapped = c(31.9, 41.5, 28.1, 33.6, 39.6, 22.9, 
36.3, 38.4, 41.3, 40.8, 32.8, 17.4, 38.8, 40.4, 29.8, 40.3, 16.1, 
19.7, 27.8, 40.6, 27.6, 26.9, 37.5, 25.7, 27.7, 41.3, 18.2, 17.6, 
39.7, 42.5, 40.8, 40.9, 41.8, 21.7, 32.7, 40.2, 39.2, 19.8, 41.9, 
21.9, 36.9, 39.8, 35.6, 31.4, 33.4, 35, 17.1, 40.2, 30.4, 29.1, 
42, 41.8, 18.6, 41.1, 23.6, 41, 39.7, 25.4, 22, 41.4, 40.4, 40.7, 
42.2, 41.1, 42.5, 30.4, 35.8, 40.4, 19.4, 38.4, 19.9, 38.1, 19.2, 
35.1, 17.7, 41.6, 34.6, 17.1, 40.3, 40.5, 30.2, 24.5, 27.3, 38.7, 
32.9, 18.5, 26.2, 33.6, 39, 39.8, 40.6, 30.6, 33.6, 39.8, 28.9, 
17.5, 41.1, 25.7, 40.2, 39.9)), .Names = c("xmapped", "ymapped"
), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Currently I use the following code to map the values in *unrounded_coords* to their nearest value in *rounded_coords*:

```
output.df <- apply(unrounded_coords, 1, FUN = function(x) {
    zed <- sqrt((x[1] - rounded_coords$xspots)^2 + (x[2] - rounded_coords$yspots)^2)
    return(c(rounded_coords$xspots[which.min(zed)], rounded_coords$yspots[which.min(zed)]))
  }) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c('xrounded', 'yrounded'))
```

Unfortunately, this function on my entire dataframe takes too long to run (I am using this in a Shiny application and this function has to run somewhat frequently). Any thoughts on how I could speed this up are greatly appreciated.

EDIT - the reason the code takes quite long is because, for each point in unrounded_coords (my dataframe has 40,000 rows, and this dataframe grows daily), it needs to compute the distance with each of ~1,000 points in rounded_coords. That is 40,000,000 computations, and I'm not sure how to get this number lower.

EDIT2 - the column names xmapped and ymapped in the unrounded_coords dataframe may be misleading. These are obviously the unmapped values, and the column names should probably be xraw, yraw, or something like that.

Comment: is your data streaming to the app live? is it stored in a db? given the large volume of calculations you expect the app to do, and growing as you say, you really need to offload that work (to say SQL for example) and then pull in the calculated values directly

Comment: pulled into R using an API. will need to stay within R for this.

Comment: there is no reason why you can't have a process pulling down data from the API and working on it independently of your shiny app, trying to do it all inline will result in a substandard user experience

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but the function as it currently stands take ~5-10 seconds to run, and that's a 5-10 second lag for the user when launching the app.

Comment: the code is not actually run within the shiny app, it's part of the pre-processing. ultimately 5-10 second wait isn't terrible, but it's a bad user experience to have to wait 10+ seconds for a shiny app to launch.

Comment: @Canovice make a loading screen then, or, maybe look at using multi-core version of the code to speed it up

Comment: shiny apps can have loading screens? did not know that

Comment: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny#loading-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will be any faster but you can give it a go.

```
library(spatstat)

# this calculates a distance matrix
# each value in rounded values has every distance to a point in unrounded as a row
distances <- crossdist(X = rounded_coords[, 1], 
                      Y = rounded_coords[, 2],
                      x2 = unrounded_coords[, 1],
                      y2 = unrounded_coords[, 2])

# if each column is an unrounded, you want the column min position
min_locations <- apply(distances, 2, which.min)

# then subset rounded_coords to get the coordinate that are closest
mapped_coords <- rounded_coords[min_locations, ]
names(mapped_coords) <- c('xrounded', 'yrounded')
```

Comment: much cleaner than the OPs code, however, I agree it is unlikely to deliver the performance improvement required to provide a decent user experience in shiny

Comment: yeah this runs at roughly the same speed as my code, thanks for sharing though, definitely cleaner.